# SSRS Report Builder returns error when entering more than one value in a parameter filter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have created a report in Report Builder that has 10 filters (parameters) that can be set by the user. Several of these need to accept more than one free-text value, like MemberNumber (e.g. 12345678A,56789098F). I've got it so that it runs fine with no values (required, returns all results), and returns expected results when one filter value added. But when I add two, in this example, MemberNumbers, I get an error:

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
   Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
      For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

[image: Entering multiple values in filter]

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the report server. So, I'm hoping the solution is obvious. Here's what I'm doing now, and what I've tried.

**In the SQL:**

```
AND (acl.MemberNum in (@MemberNumber) OR (@MemberNumber=''))
```

From previous searching, it looked like that second (@MemberNumber='') is required so that an empty filter will also return results.

**In Dataset Properties > Parameters:**

I have tried...

1. Parameter Name: @MemberNumber, Parameter Value: @MemberNumber
2. Parameter Name: @MemberNumber, Expr/Fx: =JOIN(Parameters!MemberNumber.Value,",")
3. Parameter Name: @MemberNumber, Expr/Fx: =SPLIT(JOIN(Parameters!MemberNumber.Value,","),",")

**Then in Parameters > MemberNumber > Report Parameter Properties**

[image: Allow Blanks and Allow Multiple Values set]

Then, Available Values = None, and Default Values = No default value ... as I want this to start out blank, and will often be left blank.

**Another thing I tried**, that does seem to work was to use this in the SQL:

```
AND (acl.MemberNum in (@MemberNumber) OR 'ALL' IN (@MemberNumber))
```

And then fill out Dataset Properties and Parameter settings like:

[image: Dataset Properties>Parameters]

[image: Parameter Properties for MemberNumber]

But having **ALL** as a default value in all those fields (7 of them) is a bit of a usability foul, to say the least.

**How can I have a UI with seven user filters that can all be blank, or accept multiple user values, without putting ALL or some other dummy text in them?**

Comment: Have you tried setting the default value to an empty string? `=''`